# Динамическая смена Toolbar Android

Tags: java, android, xml, search

Хотел сделать поиск в приложении. После нажатия на кнопку "Лупа"(которая является элементом Menu) должен меняться Toolbar.

Отлавливаю нажатие в методе `onOptionsItemSelected` Но после вызова метода setSupportActionBar(searchToolbar) ничего не меняется.
Подскажите как это сделать ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в сегодняшнем [Android Weekly](http://us2.campaign-archive.com/?u=887caf4f48db76fd91e20a06d&id=5f639dab6b) была [статья](https://medium.com/@alexstyl/https-medium-com-alexstyl-animating-the-toolbar-7a8f1aab39dd#.933vxy39x) на эту тему. Советую подписаться на рассылку (и почитать прошлые рассылки) - узнаете много интересного. А вообще вам нужна не кнопка лупы, а виджет [`SearchView`](http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/), там все уже сделано.